# getline() keeps taking the same line as input after a reading a few lines

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, stl, c++14

I tried to solve this problem from Hackerrank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-maps/problem, but I keep getting this unexpected output due to **`getline()`** reading the same input over and over. Here is my code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, type, mark;
    string line, name;
    map<string, int> stud;

    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        getline(cin, line);
        //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        stringstream line2(line);
        line2 >> type >> name;
        //cout << "String "<< line << "\n";

        if(type == 1) {
            line2 >> mark;
            auto itr = stud.find(name);

            if(itr == stud.end()) {
                stud[name] = mark;
            }
            else {
                itr->second = itr->second + mark;
            }
        }

        else if(type == 2) {
            stud[name] = 0;
        }

        else {
            auto itr = stud.find(name);

            if(itr != stud.end()) {
                cout << itr->second << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My Input

```
43
1 tmni 783
1 efukng 259
1 tmni 23
1 wibzw 987
1 pjju 178
1 wibzw 255
2 bpgwa
3 efukng
1 egkjsb 100
3 wibzw
3 egkjsb
1 efukng 128
3 egkjsb
2 tmni
1 tmni 12
3 wibzw
3 efukng
1 egkjsb 10
3 pjju
```

My Output

```
259
1242
100
100
1242
387   //works fine till here
178   //Problem starts from here
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
178
```

As you can see, it works fine till 387, but keeps repeating the same value after 178.

Comment: Your stream might be failing to read somehow, and you're not `clear()`ing the stream.

Comment: Always check the stream state after an IO transaction. ALWAYS.

Comment: Your input file claims 43 lines of data, but only has 20 lines of data.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I didn't see that there were more truncated testcases below. And since I had already defined input for n iterations, it was has been reading the same line after the input has ended. Anyway, thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//...
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    getline(cin, line);
//...
```

Should be

```
//...
int i = 0;
while(getline(cin, line) && i < n){
    i++;

//....
```

If you don't check the result of the input operation all sorts of things can go wrong.

Comment: No, I just misinterpreted the output. `n` is 43. There are most definitely not 43 lines of input provided. Software bug exposed by PEBCAK.

Comment: @user4581301, hehe, yes like almost always.